# My Experience iPhone application binary upload to APP STORE

Tags: iphone, upload, binary, app-store, application-loader

I used X-Code 3.2

**Problem 1**:After installing Application Loader i tried to upload my binary, Error i got was **"UNABLE TO UNZIP THE BINARY FILE"**

**Solution**: Goto  **build/distribution-iphoneos/** inside that you have .app file compress it and that compressed file is to be uploaded.

upload should be done through APPLICATION LOADER. compress it we will get .app.zip this is the one which i have succeeded in uploading.

**Problem2**: Application started upload and suddenly error popped up **"UNABLE TO VERIFY ICON DIMENTIONS ,NO ICON IMAGE FOUND,YOUR MINIMUM OS VERSION IS BELOW 3.2,SO YOU MUST DEFINE CFBUNDLEICON....."**

**Solution**:By mistake i named my main icon images as **App_Icon.png, App_icon@2x.png** when i **replaced with Icon.png and Icon@2x.png** this error is solved

Comment: Hope this mite help some one :)

Comment: **My application accepted by apple** ...:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Xcode4 and submit your application through that.  It does a lot of things to help automate the submission and verify you have everything in place you need.